# Sencha Cmd 3.1.2 ignoring isIconPrecomposed property

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd, sencha-touch-2.2, sencha-command

According to [this documentation](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-isIconPrecomposed), the `Ext.application()` config param has an `isIconPrecomposed` property, but it is not working whatsoever when packaged with Sencha Cmd 3.1.2

Our custom icons are working fine, but this silly gloss does not work with our artwork.

- Framework: Sencha Touch 2.2.1
- Sencha Cmd: 3.1.2
- Command line: "sencha app build native"
- iOS: 6.1.3

**Is anyone else using Sencha Cmd with `isIconPrecomposed: true` ?**